# How to set logoUrl to display the logo image in the THREDDS data server?

Tags: data, netcdf, server, thredds

According to https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/tds/5.2/userguide/tds_config_ref.html#server-information:

> The best way to use your own logo is to put it in the
> ${tds.content.root.path}/thredds/public/ directory, and specify it in
> serverInformation as /thredds/, e.g.: /thredds/yourIcon.gif

I tried both PNG and GIF images. However, the image of the logo could not be shown by this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is going to be modified addressing this issue in the near future.

More information can be found at https://github.com/Unidata/tds/issues/483